# Is it possible to alter table's tablespace in oracle's trigger while creating this table?

Tags: oracle, triggers, ora-00600

I write a trigger to alter table's tablespace while creating a table, but it encounter ORA-00600. So I wonder whether it is possible to do this.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this ?

Comment: This is one proposal to solve a client's problem, but now it may not be possible.

Comment: If we knew the problem we might be able to help. If you're creating the table from a script why not just modify the script? If you're using datapump you can remap tablespaces. Etc.

Comment: Each oracle user has a default tablespace (`select USERNAME,DEFAULT_TABLESPACE from dba_users;
`). The default tablespace is used during creation new table. You can change it using alter, or specify when you are creating user.

Comment: It works when I move tablespace after creating a table, but it does not in trigger. I have verified that it is not allowed to create a table and alter the tablespace in one transaction in oracle. The case is that we create new tablespace to store data,  but they don't want to change their application code, so we have to change the tablespace while creating tables.